# What is the formula for a projection of $f(x,y)$ on a plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ (defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^2$), suppose it is plotted in 3D, as $z=f(x,y)$. What would be the formula of its projection $g(x)$ (the shadow it casts) on the, say, $x-z$ plane? At first I thought it'd be something like

$$g(x) = \max_{y\in \mathbb{R}}f(x,y)$$

but this makes no sense when $f$ is negative... so it'd be either min or max, depending on the profile? I'm sort of stuck trying to imagine this...

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck trying to imagine what you are stuck trying to imagine. But possibly you are looking for contour lines. Look it up on a calculus book, or wikipedia. What you do is to project a subset of the surface generated by $z=f(x,y)$ onto one of the coordinated planes.

Generally you have a relation between $x,y,z$ and then you pick a "level" or subset of points of the surface. This is done by intersecting the surface with a plane parallel to the coordinated plane of your interest. For instance if you have $-z^2+x^2+y^2=0$ and you want to plot the projection of the surface generated by this relation onto the $xy$ plane, then you would set $z=k$ which leads to $x^2+y^2=k^2$. This will tell you that the projection onto the $xy$ plane will be a circumference centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $k$.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to imagine: I have a 3d plot, some sort of function of two variables, it looks like a sort of hill, let's say. I shine a flashlight perpendicular to the x-z plane and my hill casts a shadow on the plane. I want to know the equation of the line that is the outline of that shadow.

Comment: @DepeHb Then you are definitely thinking about contour lines.

Answer (score 1):

A plane is defined in 3D by it's normal and distance $d$ from the origin. The 3D Cartesian vector of your function plotted in 3D would be $\vec{v}=(x, y, f(x,y))$, and the normal of the $x-z$ plane is $\vec{n}=(0, 1, 0)$ (obviously $d = 0$). From there, you just need to take $\vec{v}$ minus the projection of $\vec{v}$ onto $\vec{n}$.
$$
\vec{v_p}=(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n})\vec{n}
$$$$
\vec{v_r}=\vec{v}-\vec{v_p}=\vec{v}-(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n})\vec{n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The two-variable function will define a surface in 3D:

[image]

If that surface is projected  onto a plane, I would expect an area:

[image]

That area should be defined by two functions, and it should be possible to find them. If projecting onto the XZ plane, I would consider the maximum and minimum value of z at each value of x:

Keeping x fixed, I could find the min and max of z with the derivative respect y.